# How to use JestJS with a database?

Tags: express, sequelize.js, jestjs

I am working on a new project using Jest, Express and Sequelize to create an API.

I have some endpoints working, and am writing tests for each of my endpoints.

Coming from the Ruby on Rails world, I am used to writing tests where the database is cleaned between every test.

**This seems to be impossible in Jest because there does not appear to be a way to not have tests clobber the database since they are all running in parallel**

With that in mind, I created this global `beforeAll` function in `tests/support/setup.js` and configured Jest to use this method before all my specs run:

```
// package.json
{...
"jest": {
    "setupFilesAfterEnv": [
      "<rootDir>/tests/support/setup.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

```
// tests/support/setup.js

import models from '../../db/models'


global.beforeAll(async () => {
  await models.sequelize.drop()
  await models.sequelize.sync()
})
```

But it looks like this doesn't work either, but I think this is actually running the `beforeAll` method before each test suite....so the database still gets clobbered.

Right now, Jest seems useless to me when used with a database. Am I missing something?

What are some methods for using Jest with a database where each test is run with a pristine database?

Comment: I don't know about sequel but for [mangoDB](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/mongodb) you can check here

Comment: This is not relevant because in this example the setup does not tear down the dab between tests as is desired in my setup, which 8s what i’ve always used and seen in integration and in tear suites.